# static link to ldd output libraries

Tags: gcc, static-linking

Static link to ldd output dynamic libraries except for glibc.

I've been using ffmpeg to extract rtsp key frames and I want to make the c program work on xilinx zyqn board after static compiling. But after trying several times, I still could not make it work.

Here is the output of ldd:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff8b1cf000)

libavutil-ffmpeg.so.54 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil-ffmpeg.so.54 (0x00007f12f1da9000)
libavformat-ffmpeg.so.56 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat-ffmpeg.so.56 (0x00007f12f19aa000)
libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56 (0x00007f12f0579000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f12f01af000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f12efea6000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f12efc89000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f12efa85000)
libssh-gcrypt.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh-gcrypt.so.4 (0x00007f12ef83c000)
librtmp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0x00007f12ef620000)
libz.so.1 => /home/wyh/miniconda2/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f12ef409000)
libmodplug.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmodplug.so.1 (0x00007f12ef07e000)
libgme.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgme.so.0 (0x00007f12eee30000)
libbluray.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbluray.so.1 (0x00007f12eebe7000)
libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f12ee8b7000)
libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f12ee6a7000)
libswresample-ffmpeg.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswresample-ffmpeg.so.1 (0x00007f12ee48a000)
libva.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva.so.1 (0x00007f12ee26e000)
libzvbi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzvbi.so.0 (0x00007f12edfe3000)
libxvidcore.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxvidcore.so.4 (0x00007f12edccf000)
libx265.so.79 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx265.so.79 (0x00007f12ed0b0000)
libx264.so.148 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx264.so.148 (0x00007f12ecd0c000)
libwebp.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.5 (0x00007f12ecab0000)
libwavpack.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwavpack.so.1 (0x00007f12ec887000)
libvpx.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.3 (0x00007f12ec463000)
libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007f12ec1ba000)
libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007f12ebf8f000)
libtwolame.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtwolame.so.0 (0x00007f12ebd6c000)
libtheoraenc.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoraenc.so.1 (0x00007f12ebb2d000)
libtheoradec.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoradec.so.1 (0x00007f12eb913000)
libspeex.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspeex.so.1 (0x00007f12eb6fa000)
libsnappy.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so.1 (0x00007f12eb4f2000)
libshine.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libshine.so.3 (0x00007f12eb2e5000)
libschroedinger-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libschroedinger-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f12eb010000)
libopus.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopus.so.0 (0x00007f12eadc6000)
libopenjpeg.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjpeg.so.5 (0x00007f12eaba3000)
libmp3lame.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmp3lame.so.0 (0x00007f12ea92e000)
libgsm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsm.so.1 (0x00007f12ea720000)
libcrystalhd.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrystalhd.so.3 (0x00007f12ea505000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f12ea2e3000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f12f2018000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f12ea0db000)
libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f12e9dfa000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f12e9bb0000)
libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x00007f12e997d000)
libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007f12e9747000)
libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f12e94c7000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /home/wyh/miniconda2/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f12e918d000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /home/wyh/miniconda2/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f12e8f7b000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f12e8bc0000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f12e897d000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f12e86d3000)
libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f12e846f000)
libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0x00007f12e823c000)
libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f12e8029000)
libsoxr.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoxr.so.0 (0x00007f12e7dc4000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f12e7b9f000)
libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007f12e7994000)
libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007f12e778b000)
liborc-0.4.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0x00007f12e750b000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f12e72f7000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f12e7025000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f12e6df6000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f12e6bf2000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f12e69e7000)
libicuuc.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 (0x00007f12e6653000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f12e642a000)
libffi.so.6 => /home/wyh/miniconda2/lib/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f12e6221000)
libgomp.so.1 => /home/wyh/miniconda2/lib/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f12e5ffe000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f12e5dfa000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f12e5bdf000)
libicudata.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55 (0x00007f12e4128000)
```

How can I correctly link to the all the static libs above? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a nightmare. You need static versions of all these libraries (*.a files instead of *.so files). Also, when the *.so files are present, the *.a files will be ignored by the linker.

You are better off just using shared linking and bundling the *.so files you need together with your application. Add an rpath to your build flags to make the executable load the bundled libraries. If you ship them in a `lib` directory alongside the application executable, you would need to add `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,$ORIGIN/lib` to your GCC flags.

Another possible solution is creating an AppImage:

https://appimage.org

This works extremely well for Intel-based Linux. I don't know how well it works for ARM.